# How do I set useDateTimeOffset in Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

My command line is:

```
openapi-generator generate -g csharp-netcore --api-package net.windward.rest.dotnet.client -packageName=net.windward.rest.dotnet.client -packageVersion=20.1 -useDateTimeOffset=true -o clients/csharp -i oas.yaml
```

And it does not like the -useDateTimeOffset. I've tried --useDateTimeOffset and I've tried spacing the true instead of the =. THey all fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instead using `--additional-properties`:

```
openapi-generator generate -g csharp-netcore --api-package net.windward.rest.dotnet.client --additional-properties useDateTimeOffset=true,packageName=net.windward.rest.dotnet.client,packageVersion=20.1 -o clients/csharp -i oas.yaml
```